# jq update objects based on array of object names

Tags: jq

I'm trying to update some objects based on a list of objects. For example I want to turn this:

```
{
  "names": ["a","c"],
  "del": {
      "a": true,
      "b": true,
      "c": true
  }
}
```

into this:

```
{
  "names": ["a","c"],
  "del": {
      "a": false,
      "b": true,
      "c": false
  }
}
```

So for each object name in `.names` update its corresponding object in `.del` 
The solution I can up with seems inefficient and I was wondering if there was a better way.

`[foreach .names[] as $name (.;.del[$name] = false ; .) ] | last`

Answer (score 1):

I think using `last` is a good indication that you don't care about intermediate values and since foreach[1](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#foreach) is described as:

> The foreach syntax is similar to reduce, but intended to allow the construction of limit and reducers that produce intermediate results

There is an equivalent reduce:

`reduce .names[] as $name (.; .del[$name]=false)`

When both are possible, reduce is more efficient in terms of code as communication with other programmers and potential performance. (If the `reduce` implementation were found to be slower than a pattern with `foreach`, then jq could reimplement `reduce` with that pattern.)

Comment: Correct, I do not care about the  intermediate values so this is much more efficient.